# Cert-manager error stuck in certficateRequest approved

Tags: kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, cert-manager

I am trying to deploy Cert-manager in my OKE (Oracle Kubernetes engine) version 1.24.1 everything works correctly, but when I try to auto-generate a certificate from my ingress with my issuer(in a state ready) the certificate is created correctly but is in a false state and when I describe it I found that it doesn't found the secret which is normal but after that, it generates a certificaterequest which is in the approved state but nothing else and the secret for my domain is not created.

issuer :

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-nginx
  namespace: default
spec:
 acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: xxxxxxxxx
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-nginx-private-key
    solvers:
    - http01:
       ingress:
         class: nginx
```

[image: issuer]

certificaterequest :

[image: Certificaterequest]
certificate  :

[image: Certificate]

and i find nothings in logs of cert-manager it just telling me that the certificaterequest is approved,

what i have done:
try to upgrade the version of cert-manager but nothing, now I am using version v1.12.1 of cert-manager

if you need more information just ask :D